# Calculate Daily Returns with Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is my Pandas data frame:

```
prices = pandas.DataFrame([1035.23, 1032.47, 1011.78, 1010.59, 1016.03, 1007.95, 
              1022.75, 1021.52, 1026.11, 1027.04, 1030.58, 1030.42,
              1036.24, 1015.00, 1015.20])
```

Here is my `daily_return` function:

```
def daily_return(prices):
    return prices[:-1] / prices[1:] - 1
```

Here is output that comes from this function:

```
0    NaN
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0
6      0
7      0
8      0
9      0
10     0
11     0
12     0
13     0
14   NaN
```

Why am I having this output?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because operations will do alignment on index, you can convert one of the DataFrames to array:

```
prices[:-1].values / prices[1:] - 1
```

or

```
prices[:-1] / prices[1:].values - 1
```

depends on what the index of the result you want.

or use `shift()` method:

```
prices.shift(1) / prices - 1
```

and:

```
prices / prices.shift(1) - 1
```

Comment: `shift` is much better than going down to `values`.

Comment: Be careful; depending how your prices data is sorted by date (asc, desc), the shift example would be wrong. `prices / prices.shift(1) - 1` is for ascending order. 

(`Date,SPY,XOM
2012-07-02,136.51,84.79
2012-07-03,137.41,85.72`) 

so on

Comment: @mimoralea
So for descending order it's `df['Adj Close'] / df['Adj Close'].shift(-1) - 1` right?!?

Comment: Why do we need only one of the arguments to be converted to array? I find it more intuitive if both are converted to array values and perform division.

Answer (score 86):

Why not use the very convenient **`pct_change`** method provided by `pandas` by default:

```
import pandas as pd

prices = pandas.DataFrame([1035.23, 1032.47, 1011.78, 1010.59, 1016.03, 1007.95, 
          1022.75, 1021.52, 1026.11, 1027.04, 1030.58, 1030.42,
          1036.24, 1015.00, 1015.20])

daily_return = prices.pct_change(1) # 1 for ONE DAY lookback
monthly_return = prices.pct_change(21) # 21 for ONE MONTH lookback
annual_return = prices.pct_change(252) # 252 for ONE YEAR lookback
```

**Original** `prices`:

```
print(prices)
          0                                                                    
0   1035.23                                                                    
1   1032.47                                                                    
2   1011.78                                                                    
3   1010.59                                                                    
4   1016.03                                                                    
5   1007.95                                                                    
6   1022.75                                                                    
7   1021.52                                                                    
8   1026.11                                                                    
9   1027.04                                                                    
10  1030.58                                                                    
11  1030.42                                                                    
12  1036.24                                                                    
13  1015.00                                                                    
14  1015.20
```

**Daily Return** as ***`prices.pct_change(1)`***:

```
print(prices.pct_change(1))
           0                                                                   
0        NaN                                                                   
1  -0.002666                                                                   
2  -0.020039                                                                   
3  -0.001176                                                                   
4   0.005383                                                                   
5  -0.007953                                                                   
6   0.014683                                                                   
7  -0.001203                                                                   
8   0.004493                                                                   
9   0.000906                                                                   
10  0.003447                                                                   
11 -0.000155                                                                   
12  0.005648                                                                   
13 -0.020497                                                                   
14  0.000197
```

Comment: When your data is asc. (2016-01-03, 2016-01-02, etc.) use:
`df['Adj Close'].pct_change(-1)`

Comment: any idea why pct_change answers are slightly different to just doing: newValue - oldValue / newValue for example (1032.47 - 1035.23) / 1032.47 gives -0.0026732 and not the -0.002666 answer given by pct_change?

Comment: you have to divide by the strat value, not the end value... correct answer is: (1032.47 - 1035.23) / 1035.23 = -0.002666

Comment: I know this is an old answer but the documentation doesn't say anything about values you have used in pct_change, 1 for daily, 21 for monthly and 252 for yearly. Could you explain how this is working or these values are referring to the periods specific to this question?

Comment: @IshanSharma It's all about the "*context*". When we are talking about **stocks markets**, 1, 21, 252 are the right periods, because the stocks markets are **not trading everyday**.

Answer (score 4):

Just a bit of complement to @YaOzl 's answer, and in case if someone would read this. 
If your return data is a panel spreadsheet with several stocks:

```
>>> prices = pandas.DataFrame(
{"StkCode":["StockA","StockA","StockA","StockA","StockA","StockB","StockB","StockB","StockB","StockB","StockC","StockC","StockC","StockC","StockC",], 
"Price":[1035.23, 1032.47, 1011.78, 1010.59, 1016.03, 1007.95, 1022.75, 1021.52, 1026.11, 1027.04, 1030.58, 1030.42, 1036.24, 1015.00, 1015.20]}
)
```

Which gives you:

```
      Price StkCode
0   1035.23  StockA
1   1032.47  StockA
2   1011.78  StockA
3   1010.59  StockA
4   1016.03  StockA
5   1007.95  StockB
6   1022.75  StockB
7   1021.52  StockB
8   1026.11  StockB
9   1027.04  StockB
10  1030.58  StockC
11  1030.42  StockC
12  1036.24  StockC
13  1015.00  StockC
14  1015.20  StockC
```

Then you could simply jointly use **.pct_change(k)** with **.groupby(StkCode)**. 
And it is thound times faster than using an iterator...(I tried on my dataset, successfully shrink the process time **from 10 hrs to 20 seconds!!**)

```
>>> prices["Return"] = prices.groupby("StkCode")["Price"].pct_change(1)
```

Gives you:

```
      Price StkCode    Return
0   1035.23  StockA       NaN
1   1032.47  StockA -0.002666
2   1011.78  StockA -0.020039
3   1010.59  StockA -0.001176
4   1016.03  StockA  0.005383
5   1007.95  StockB       NaN
6   1022.75  StockB  0.014683
7   1021.52  StockB -0.001203
8   1026.11  StockB  0.004493
9   1027.04  StockB  0.000906
10  1030.58  StockC       NaN
11  1030.42  StockC -0.000155
12  1036.24  StockC  0.005648
13  1015.00  StockC -0.020497
14  1015.20  StockC  0.000197
```

Answer (score 4):

I like all the above methods. However, we can do it this way as well:

```
daily_returns = (prices/prices.shift(1)) -1
daily_returns.iloc[0,:] = 0
```

*prices is pandas dataframe and daily_returns will be Series object.